# Node.js Vorpal CLI - include subcommands as one command

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, inquirer, vorpal, inquirerjs

Say we have this:

```
  vorpal.command('find [sumanOptions] [folder]')
  .description('find test files to run')
  .action(function (args: Array<string>, cb: Function) {
     // args => {sumanOptions: 'a b c'}
  });
```

how can I pass a string of commands ('subcommands') for sumanOptions? something like this:

`vorpal> find "a b c" myfolder`

such that in the args in the action callback, looks like:

```
 // args => {sumanOptions: 'a b c'}
```

is this possible? or is this problem the "subcommands" issue I have been seeing in the issue tracker? I'd like to be able to do this, and so far, have not been able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Running `find "a b c" myfolder` currently gives args `{ options: {}, sumanOptions: 'a b c', folder: 'myfolder' }`. How is that different from what you require?

Comment: my example wasn't good enough - the problem occurs when I include `--` and `-` in the `sumanOptions` option. I will update the question.